# Firebase Cloud Messaging received BUT doesn't Popup!!! - KOTLIN

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

### This is my code!

I'm building an application that receives notifications from firebase.
The App receiving the notification but doesn't popup it.

Any Help!

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {


    val TAG = "FirebaseMessagingService"

    override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {    

        super.onMessageReceived(p0)
        Log.d(TAG, "{$p0}")


        if (p0.notification !=null){
            showNotification(p0.notification?.title, p0.notification?.body)

        }

    }


    private fun showNotification(title: String?, body: String?){

        val intent=Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivities(
            this,
            0,
            arrayOf(intent),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
        //val soundUri=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)


        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_border)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setPriority(2)

        val notificationManager=getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())


    }

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: $token")

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the notification channel which came out with Android 8.0.

Call this function before building your notification.

```
private fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            val existingChannel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID)
            if (existingChannel == null) {
                // Create the NotificationChannel
                val name = context.getString(R.string.defaultChannel)
                val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                val mChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance)
                mChannel.description = context.getString(R.string.notificationDescription)
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
            }
        }
    }
```

And use this with your code

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).apply {
    cancelAll() // Remove prior notifications; only allow one at a time.
    notify(1 or your notification id, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

instead of

```
val notificationManager=getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager 
notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
            .setTicker(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentText(message)

    if (bitmap != null) {
        notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(bitmap)
    }

    val notificationManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId,
                channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build())
```